# Linking kernel - i386 architecture of input file is incompatible with i386:x86_64 output

Tags: c, assembly, linker

I am trying to move on from my assembly file kernel stage to my C file kernel stage (finally...). But, I am having some trouble in the process of linking my compiled C kernel to my compiled assembly kernel entry program.

Here is the code for my kernel_entry.asm file.

```
[BITS 32]           ; Starting in 32 bit protected mode
[EXTERN main]           ; Extern to C file main function

call main           ; Invoke main in our C kernel

jmp $               ; Jump here - Infinite loop
```

Here is the code for my kernel.c file.

```
void main() {
  char* video_memory = (char*) 0xB8000;
  *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

Here are the command lines I am using to compile them.

```
nasm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o kernel_entry.asm
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x0500 kernel_entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary
```

The last command line gives me this error.

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file `kernel_entry.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000000500
```

Note: I am loading my kernel to the address and offset 0x0000:0x0500, which is why I use -Ttext 0x0500, I am unsure why the second ld warning appears but for now it seems unimportant (although if you offer any help in that regard it would be appreciated as well).

Can anyone tell me why I cannot link these files together? I am also running on Ubuntu dekstop 64 bit. Thank you in advance for any help you may give.

Comment: Have you tried telling `gcc` and `ld` to generate 32-bit code?  (By default, on a 64-bit system, they will want to make 64-bit binaries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you're compiling this code on a 64-bit system. As such, `kernel.o` is a 64-bit binary, and cannot be linked with the 32-bit `kernel_entry.o`.

Since you don't have any code in place to get the system into long mode, you probably want to compile the "kernel" as 32-bit code. Use `-m32` to trigger this:

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
    ^^^^
```